# If-then statement in jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, css-selectors, conditional-statements

Currently, I need to check a specific anchor tag to see if it contains certain text. If it does then I need it to change the text of another element. Just as an example, I have the following code. However, no matter what I put in as being contained within an anchor tag, it always alerts "yup!".

```
if ($("a:contains('Level 2 (Admin Only)')")) {
    alert("yup!");
} 
else {
    alert("nope!");
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I use a different selector method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `$("a:contains('Level 2 (Admin Only)')")` is **always** true.

Try this:

```
if($("a:contains('Level 2 (Admin Only)')").length) {
   alert("yup!");
}else{
   alert("nope!");
}
```

Comment: `length != 0`? Meh. This is JavaScript. Use the truthiness!

Comment: @MattBall just wanted to keep the if statement the same as the OP had it.

Answer (score 5):

You have to check the size of the jQuery object. jQuery returns an object, consisting of all matched elements.

```
 // If .length == zero, it evaluates to false in an if condition
if ($("a:contains('Level 2 (Admin Only)')").length) {
```

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery method *always* returns an object whether the selector matched any elements or not; and objects are *always* truthy.

You should use the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length) attribute instead, which will be *truthy* if an element was matched, and *falsy* if one wasn't.

```
if ($("a:contains('Level 2 (Admin Only)')").length) {
   alert("yup!");
}else{
   alert("nope!");
}
```